# Never ending discounts in ecommerce

Tags: e-commerce, data-collection, discount

What research and numbers say about having "never ending" discounts for products in ecommerce business? E.g. My client has almost all their products always discounted. I know it looks suspicious/cheap but any solid evidence?

Comment: I don't have anything regarding the UX of it, but you may find that this behavior runs into legal trouble. A quick look into Directive 98/6/EC, Article 6a suggests that discounts have to be limited in time. You/your client may want to run that by an actual lawyer though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about deceptive patterns, better known as dark patterns. Dark patterns are tricks used in websites to lure user into buying, signing up or agreeing on something. It really depends on the company and brand, but generally I'd suggest to avoid using dark patterns as most of the time it misdirects users and makes their experience unpleasant.

In some countries dark patterns are becoming illegal, for more information you should check out following source: https://www.deceptive.design/laws

Dark patterns definition with some great real world examples: https://www.gtlaw.com.au/knowledge/dark-patterns-explained

More context about history and techniques of dark patterns in the following research:
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12599-022-00783-7#Sec3